# how to get data from javascript

Tags: javascript, php

hello i want to get text from textarea and register in database but not work where is problem thanks all. $get_text show empty value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".new_post").click(function(){
            var get_text = $("#post_text").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/ajax_new_post.php",
                data: get_text,
                success: function() {
                    alert(get_text);
                    $('#post_text').val('');
                    //$(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
                    //.animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
   <textarea id="post_text" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
</body>
```

ajax_new_post.php

```
$get_text = $_GET['get_text'];
mysqli_query($Connection, "INSERT INTO posts VALUES('$ID', '$get_text')");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing key. Change your data to:

```
data: { get_text : $("#post_text").val() },
```

And your type is `POST`, so use `$_POST['get_text']` in PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using post method . So use $_POST['get_text'];

Comment: Are you sure about `$_POST['get_text']` ?

Comment: I think so > lets have atry

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are making a POST and trying to get the value as GET.

Use :

```
$get_text = $_POST['get_text'];
mysqli_query($Connection, "INSERT INTO posts VALUES('$ID', '$get_text')");
```

Comment: Are you sure about `$_POST['get_text']` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to send a JavaScript variable to your PHP file:

```
'$url = 'path/to/phpFile.php';
 $.get($url, {name: get_name(), job: get_job()});'
```

In your PHP code, get your variables from $_GET['name'] and $_GET['job'] like this:

```
<?php
    $buffer_data['name'] = $_GET['name'];
    $buffer_data['job']  = $_GET['job'];
?>
```